# Android SQLite, ask about ContentValues

Tags: database, android

i would like to know if using the class ContentValue in querys is a good practice in order to prevent SQL injection.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, whether you use `ContentValues` or use regular `SQLiteDatabase` queries, you cannot be 100% safe from SQL Injections.

With that being said, if you are comfortable using `ContentValues` its a better practice to escape any user's input, or if you want to use `SQLiteDatabase` queries look at [**`SQLiteQueryBuilder`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html), it helps structure your query.

If Android offered parameterized queries that would be hands down the best practice to protect against injections. Until then, we'll have to wait and find alternatives.